# node.js server won't start

Tags: node.js, server

I'm trying to run this extremely simple example of a server with a command 'node server.js'. This gives the message that the server is running, however, when I visit 127.0.0.1:3000 or localhost:3000 in Chrome it looks like it's stuck(rendering icon spins continuously).

Code:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer();
server.on('request',function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('Hello World \n');
})

server.listen(3000);
console.log('Server running on localhost 3000');
```

Rodrigo answered correctly. This is pulled from (node.js in action in case you have the same issue)

Comment: You need to call `res.end()` after the last `res.write()` in order to end the response.

Comment: Yep, that worked, thanks. This was pulled straight from a book I'm reading. Typical!

Comment: @JohnandLynHenry, Sorry I didn't notice the comment and you edited your question too late. Should I now take my answer back?

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros It's probably best to keep the answer there for posterity.

Comment: Well Johnand, thank you for your concern, I appreciate it. But it's enough for me if @taufique just cite my comment. After all, his answer is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `res.end()` after writing the data you want to send. It should work.

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer();
server.on('request',function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('Hello World \n');
  res.end()
})

server.listen(3000);
console.log('Server running on localhost 3000');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to end the response with `res.end()` as you can see in next example:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this simple program.

**server.js**

```
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app.js');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const  app = express();

app.use((req , res , next ) => {

    res.status(200).json({
        message:'its working'
    });

});

module.exports = app;
```